# How can I get a textual summary of changes that triggered a build in TeamCity?

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, teamcity-7.0

When you have a build trigger setup in TeamCity, TeamCity shows a nice text summary of the changes that triggered a build. I would like to use a similar summary in a build step.

How can I get a textual summary of changes?

Comment: Just to confirm I understand the question - Are you saying that you want to be able to use the text summary of what triggered the build in one of the build steps?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. In my case I'm uploading an iOS build to TestFlightApp.com and want to include a description of the changes.